# Selector for multiple attributes values in AND condition

Tags: jquery

I've the following html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div>a</div>
    <div tag="one, two, three">b</div>
    <div tag="three">c</div>
    <div tag="four, one">d</div>
    <p>e</p>
</div>
```

with `JQuery` I need to `.hide` all `#wrapper` children not contains a well known array of tag in AND condition.

Example:

For `one, three` I have:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div tag="one, two, three">b</div>
</div>
```

For a single tag I managed it to work in this way:

```
var tag= tagArray[0];

$("#wrapper> *:not([tag='" + tag + "'])").each(function (index, value) {
      $(value).hide();
});
```

But how to work with the full array? Is this the right way to accomplish this?

Comment: Let's use data-tag instead of tag.  http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/

Comment: You could try a for each to generate a list of 'nots' and then toss it in the not.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Also...wait a minute.  Why not instead just use classes?  No need for a data- attribute.  There's absolutely no reason to either make up non-standard 'tag' attributes, or even use the standard - yet in this case wholly unnecessary - data- prefixed attribute.  Just use classes.

Comment: Yes in this example I agree, `class` can be the right choice but in my real app there are other custom attributes and I need them.

Comment: Custom attributes should always start with data-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code :

```
var tagArray = ['three', 'two']


$.each(tagArray, function(){
    var tag = this;
    $("#wrapper> *").filter(function(){
        var regexp = new RegExp('\\b'+tag+'\\b');
        return !($(this).attr('tag') && $(this).attr('tag').match(regexp));
    }).hide()
})
```

You loop over the array of tag and then compare them with a regexp.

Also, it would be better to use HTML5 data-* attribute instead of customs ones.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H63Cy/1/)**